# Laravel 5: Update record without changing current date/time value of updated_at field

Tags: laravel-5, auto-update

In my Laravel 5 project, I would like to increase the number of views when a visitor come/refresh on the product page like:

```
$rds = Product::whereId($id)->first();
$rds->hits++;
$rds->save();
```

The problem is that the field: **updated_at** automatically update, which is not what I want at all because I would like to change only field: hits, not update_at field.

If I set $rds->updated_at = false; the field is updated to be '0000-00-00 00:00:0'.

Could you advise how to prevent updated_at field from automatically changing for only certain function?

Best Regards,
Naren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the timestamps to false to disable updating created_at and updated_at.

```
$rds = Product::whereId($id)->first();
$rds->hits++;
$rds->timestamps = false;
$rds->save();
```

You can have a look at the code by Laravel here in `performUpdate` method:
`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php`

```
     // First we need to create a fresh query instance and touch the creation and
     // update timestamp on the model which are maintained by us for developer
     // convenience. Then we will just continue saving the model instances.
     if ($this->timestamps && Arr::get($options, 'timestamps', true)) {
         $this->updateTimestamps();
     }
```

Comment: How about using $rds->hits++ with select join two tables? Let's say I want to join table Products with table companies, and I want to update the hits field of table Products every time a visitor come to view the product page.

Could you provide the complete coding?

Answer (score 1):

it's not `$rds->updated_at = false`, should be `$rds->timestamps = false`

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the below in your model it would disable timestamp

public $timestamps = false;

or append to the body of the method, below

$rds->timestamps = false;

NB: The first would disable timestamps permanently, while the other would not allow update of timestamp on your edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)